# Expanding my divs beyond the content

Tags: html

I have a sidebar div to the left of my main content area and a footer below.  How do I get my side bar div and main content div to both extend to my footer without filling it with content?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the min-height CSS attribute. I don't know exactly how the markup is structured, but applying it to both divs (left and main), or a surrounding container should do it.

If you need it to work in older versions of IE, you should check out one of the CSS hacks like: http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<div style="width:80%; margin:0 10% 0 10%">
     <div style="background:red; width:20%; float:left">side</div>
     <div style="background:blue; width:80%;float:right">main</div>
     <div style="background:green; clear:both;">footer</div>
</div>
```